# Java: Set a timeout for a method that checks if it can be executed again

Tags: java, methods, timeout

i'm having a routine that runs in a while(true) loop. After checking some variables with an if-statement , the class will call a method, but this method shall only be able to run once in 30 seconds. 
Let's say the if-statement returns true and the method gets called the method itself should check whether it was called in the last 30 seconds and only run if that's not the case.

I tried to google for stuff like "method timeout" but i couldn't find what i was searching for. Hope you guys know what i'm looking for.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Save the last time with `System.currentTimeMillis()` and check if the difference with the current time is greater than 30,000.

Comment: It sounds like your `while (true)` loop will be [busy-waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting); this is generally to be avoided. Why not sleep for 30 seconds before checking once again whether the method should be run, or setting up a Timer that runs once every 30 seconds to check whether the method should be run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a static variable with the timestamp of the last execution.

You can get this value with System.nanoTime().

Also, you should synchronize the block that makes the verification on a class lock, in case you're on a multithreaded environment.